# Subset moving window when using focal on raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a classified Landsat image, and I'd like to pass a filter over it converting certain cells to 0.  For some categories, I'd like to set cells to 0 unless an entire 7x7 window contains only that cell value.  For other categories, I'd like to set cells to 0 unless an entire 5x5 window contains only that cell value. And for others, set to 0 unless at 3x3 window, etc.  I've tried two ways to do this:

One is to pass multiple filters over the same raster, and then combine their outputs.  I tried this and it takes an incredibly long time, so I think it would be more efficient to pass one 7x7 filter over the raster, and have a conditional function that subsets the window to 5x5 or 3x3 based on the value of the category it is passing over.

However, it doesn't seem to be working, I think because I am having trouble referencing the 3x3 sub window within the 7x7 moving window.  How can I write a function to be used within the focal() function that references only certain cells within the moving window?

The code I am using:

```
r <- raster('myraster.tif')

FocalSelect <- function(cells){
  if (cells[c(25)]==4){
    return(4)}
  if (cells[c(25)]==9){
    return(9)}
  if (cells[c(17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33)]==rep(2,9)){
    return(2)}
  if (cells[c(17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33)]==rep(5,9)){
    return(5)}
  if (cells[c(17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33)]==rep(8,9)){
    return(8)}
  if (cells[c(seq(9,13),seq(16,20),seq(23,27),seq(30,34),seq(37,41))]==rep(1,25)){
    return(1)}
  if (cells[c(seq(9,13),seq(16,20),seq(23,27),seq(30,34),seq(37,41))]==rep(6,25)){
    return(6)}
  if (cells[c(seq(9,13),seq(16,20),seq(23,27),seq(30,34),seq(37,41))]==rep(7,25)){
    return(7)}
  if (cells==rep(3,49)){
    return(3)}
  if (cells==rep(10,49)){
    return(10)}
  if (cells==rep(11,49)){
    return(11)}
  else{
    return(0)
  }
}

out <- focal(r, matrix(rep(1,49),nrow=7),fun=FocalSelect)
```

and this give me these warnings:

```
1: In if (cells[c(17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33)] ==  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (cells[c(17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33)] ==  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (cells[c(17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33)] ==  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (cells[c(seq(9, 13), seq(16, 20), seq(23, 27), seq(30,  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (cells[c(seq(9, 13), seq(16, 20), seq(23, 27), seq(30,  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (cells[c(seq(9, 13), seq(16, 20), seq(23, 27), seq(30,  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (cells == rep(3, 49)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
8: In if (cells[c(17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33)] ==  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
9: In if (cells[c(17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33)] ==  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
10: In if (cells[c(17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33)] ==  ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

EDIT: It looks like I was subsetting the moving window correctly, but my if statement was phrased wrong.

```
if (cells[c(17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33)]==rep(2,9)){
```

should be

```
if (identical(cells[c(17,18,19,24,25,26,31,32,33)],rep(2,9))){
```